# Rendering graphs in GUI with graphviz

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz

I am trying to display a `graph` with `graphviz`. I have managed to display the graph by generating files.

Now I want to display the `graph` in `GUI with pyQT` or any other `GUI manager`. I am thinking about animating the graph for example color the nodes while using DFS or BFS algorithm.

What I have found on the internet:

- I have tried `networkx with matplotlib` but the display was a mess.
- I have thought about generating images and then render them in GUI
  but this consumes a lot of time.
- I have find `python-igraph` but it can not be customized like graphviz
  and I think it don't work with gui either.

**So what should I do?**

I am only going to use this lib in a school project so I don't want to draw the nodes by myself because it will take me some time. If there is an easy method to use the position given by graphviz I don't mind using it but plz give me some hints.

By the way, If you know any other lib i can use, please tell me.

***Note: I need to display a graph in GUI and render it in real time.***

Comment: What do you nedan with GUI? Would a web browser be ok? Is Python a requirement?

Comment: Yes Python is required.

Comment: If rendering in a web browser is an option, you can use [pygraphviz](https://pygraphviz.github.io/) (Python) on the server side to generate the *.dot* and [d3-graphviz](https://github.com/magjac/d3-graphviz) (Javascript) on the client side to render the graph and do animated transitions. See e.g. this [demo](https://bl.ocks.org/magjac/4acffdb3afbc4f71b448a210b5060bca)

Comment: Otherwise you might find something useful [here](https://www2.graphviz.org/resources/)